# Index of all words used in MS Word document

Tags: ms-word

I need to create an index at the end of a MS Word document that lists all the words used in the document, the page number where there used in alphabetical order.  Can I do this with the built in index capabilities?  If so how do I go about doing this? Or do I need a macro, and if so can someone help me with the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This takes for ever on large documents but does generate the Index fields you need to create an Index in your word document. After this macro has run you can do `References > Insert Index` to have the actual index in your document.

```vb
Dim colWords as Collection
Set colWords = New Colection
'add words you don't want to index
colWords.Add "and"
colWords.Add "you"

Dim wrd As Range
For Each wrd In ActiveDocument.Words

  'only if we have 3 chars we index
  If Len(Trim(wrd.Text)) > 2 Then

     ' prevent the field from being Indexed as well...
     Dim infield As Boolean
     infield = False
     Dim fld As Field
     For Each fld In ActiveDocument.Fields
       If (wrd.Start >= fld.Code.Start And wrd.End <= fld.Code.End) Then
         infield = True
         Exit For 'break out
       End If
     Next

     If (Not infield) Then
        ' check if we already indexed? 
        Dim findWord as String
        findWord = LCASE(wrd.Text)
        For Each cached in colWords
            if cached = findWord Then
               infield = True
               Exit For 'break out
            end If 
        Next
        If  (Not infield) Then 
           ActiveDocument.Indexes.MarkAllEntries Range:=wrd, Entry:=wrd.Text, _
             EntryAutoText:=wrd.Text, CrossReference:="", CrossReferenceAutoText:="", _
             BookmarkName:="", Bold:=False, Italic:=False

           colWords.Add findWord

         End If
     End If
   End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Rene .. will check it out!

Comment: Is there a way to speed this up as it crashes on my machine with a 86 page document?

Comment: I added a poor mans caching with a collection that holds already Indexed words for this run...

Comment: Still crashes .. I sent you an email about helping me with this.